# jsp table adding and deleteing dynamically without spoiling the row order number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i have a table in my jsp page,and also i have add or remove buttons to every row,,,and for every row it has row number in first column but if i delete particular row the row will be deleted but the order is going wrong. for example consider by default table has 5rows with each row having order number 1,2,3,4,5 and if delete 3rd row then it showing like row1,row2,row3,row5 but i want it like row 1, row 2,row 3,row 4.......for every delete or adding rows i want the rows index in order only,,,can any one help ??
well here is my code goes like this...
here i want file1 for 1st row and file 2 for 2nd row and file 3 for 3rd row etc.and if delete any particular row then the order should be again reorder as per. example u have added 4rows additionally so now table consists file1,file2,file3,file4,file5 and if we delete file 4 it should not show like file1,file2,file3,file5 it should show like file1,file2,file3,file4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   strict.dtd">      
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">  
var i=0;j=0; 
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    i++;
    j++;
    $('#HowManyRows').each(function(index) {
    $('#FirstRow').clone().appendTo('#listfiles');
});
});

});
function deleteRow(btn) {
 if(i>=1){
i--;
var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
 }
 </script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="listfiles">
    <tr id="FirstRow">
<td>File 1:<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" value="xyz"/>
Description:<input type="text" name="description" id="filename" value=""  />
<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this)">DeleteFile</a><</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" id="btnAdd">Add additional file</a>
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell me clearly... i am new to this design part??

Comment: @user3040482 well you could post your code, so we can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

**html**

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="REMOVE" class="delete"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="REMOVE" class="delete"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="REMOVE" class="delete"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="REMOVE" class="delete"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
    $(function(){
        $('.delete').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            $('#my_table tr').each(function(i){
                var index = i + 1
                $('td:first',this).text('Row ' + index);
             })
         })
     })
```

**--------------EDITED CODE--------------------------**

javascript code ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dkfG2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
           $('#FirstRow').clone().appendTo('#listfiles');
        });
    });

    function deleteRow(btn) {
         $(btn).parent().parent().remove();
    }
```

Comment: haa but i didnt implemented any code for incrementing of row number like along with the file like file 1 and then in the next row file2 and then in the next row file3.... it should come like that for every click on add button....rest of the things like dynamically adding or removing of rows are done except reordering or row number in each row beside file text......could you please help regarding that

Comment: wow...!!! thank you so much rajesh... thats what i want but its should maintain at least 1 row,it should not allow us to delete all rows,should left atleast 1 row

Comment: hey...in that table if you add new row its taking previous rows value  into the newly added row,,,,,the new rows should come with empty values,,,,can you please resolve that!!!!!